# Dynamically showing a control in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add some dynamic content to the bottom of my JQuery mobile page. The content is populated by a JavaScript file. A user navigates to this page by clicking a link on another page. When they click that link they are shown the page that is defined below. Oddly, the dynamic content does NOT show when the user arrives by the navigating from the previous page. However, if I refresh the page, the content appears. Alternatively, if I navigate to the page directly via the url, the content appears. In all three situations, no JavaScript errors are reported in the console. What am I doing wrong?

**Page.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="myPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <a href="#" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right jqm-plus" onclick="addButton_Click();">Add</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="noResults">No Results</div>
      <ul id="recentResults" data-role="listview"></ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <div id="dynamicContent">
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.mydomain.com/footerContent.js'>   
        </script>
      </div>
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/tab2" rel="external">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="/tab3" rel="external">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addButton_Click() {
        $.mobile.changePage("/add", { transition: "slide" });
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the code that generates/adds the dynamic content?

Comment: When you navigate to this page by clicking a link on another page, any JS in the <head> of this page won't be loaded. Sounds like this maybe be your issue, whenever I hear someone complaining that a page works directly but doesn't work when they navigate to it from another page, it's because they don't understand this. Is there anything in your <head> that the external dynamic JS file needs? And wasn't on the previous page?

Comment: Hello. I am referencing .js files in the <head> of the page. However, they are the exact same files in both pages. In fact, the <head> is EXACTLY the same between the two pages.

Comment: JQM(Jquery Mobile) has gone through lots of recent changes. Posting your JQuery and JQM version helps us give a better answer.

Comment: Is the dynamic content not showing at all or not being enhanced by JQM?

Answer (score 0):

Put your js that adds the content in the head of your document. Then add you dynamic content on pageinit. JQM is pulling that content into the same dom as page1 and I believe is ignoring your external script.

```
<head>
<link ....
<script ....
<script .....
<script>
$('body').delegate('#myPage','pageinit',function(){
    $('#dynamicContent').append('add ground breaking dynamic content here');
});
</script>
</head>
```